Wagtail Migrate DB and S3 images beween DEV and Staging
We are trying to migrate our Wagtail site data from DEV to Staging environments
We have copied the S3 images from DEV to Staging using aws s3 copy
We have dumped the postgres database to a file and imported into our Staging database
The tables now in the Staging database have the same number of pages in wagtailcore_pages and in our custom image model as the DEV database
However the Wagtail UI shows less Pages, Images, Documents, Media files despite the DB tables seeming to be the same
At a loss
We have flushed Redis
